# Android: Json Parsing issue

Tags: android, json, parsing

I have a Json Array like this:

```
[["a", "values1"], ["b", "values2"], ["c", "values3"]]
```

I want to parse this array in android application and my code is:

```
try {
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(cJson);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONArray jsonNavigation = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
    Log.i(TAG, jsonNavigation.toString());
}
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get exploded values like:

```
["a", "values1"]
["b", "values2"]
["c", "values3"]
```

Then I would like to navigate every line to get "a" and "values1" for first line, "b" and "values2" for the second and so on, but I can not find the right code. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 6):

Try the below

```
  try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(cJson);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONArray jsonNavigation = jsonArray.getJSONArray(i);
            for(int j =0; j<jsonNavigation.length();j++)
            Log.i("........", ""+jsonNavigation.get(j));
        }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Log

```
09-19 15:11:44.289: I/........(2922): a
09-19 15:11:44.289: I/........(2922): values1
09-19 15:11:44.289: I/........(2922): b
09-19 15:11:44.289: I/........(2922): values2
09-19 15:11:44.289: I/........(2922): c
09-19 15:11:44.289: I/........(2922): values3
```